# How to decrypt PKCS#7 enveloped data with Azure Key Vault

Tags: c#, azure, encryption, pkcs#7, azure-keyvault

I have certificates with private keys installed in Azure Key Vault, and I need to decrypt mime-content of type '`application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data`' (Cryptographic Message Syntax)

Can this be done with Azure Key Vault and C#/.NET?
Seems to me that Decrypt only works with raw data against the KeyVault client.
Is there some easy way to unwrap the mime content and decrypt bytes, manually?

Comment: welp, there's the unwrap permission, so there probably is an unwrap command, have you tried that?

Comment: There is a CMS component in the bouncy castle implementation for C#. *Possibly* you can configure that with a private key to do the final raw decrypt (or indeed unwrap). Otherwise it *is* open source...

Comment: Does [this](http://www.davidaiken.com/2012/02/24/encrypting-and-decrypting-in-windows-azure/) answer your question? Note that PKCS#7 is the name / number of the standard document. It defines the Cryptographic Message Syntax or CMS. CMS is the better search term.

Comment: EnvelopedCms is part of the framework and can decrypt for you. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs/tests/EnvelopedCms/DecryptTests.cs#L199 is sort of an example.

Comment: +1 to @bartonjs, this is pretty standard. You just need to make sure you have accesss to the private key